# Como utilizar o WP-API para reproduzir um vídeo de um post?

Tags: android, wordpress

Queria saber como faço para pegar o vídeo de uma postagem no wordpress e reproduzí-lo no app. Estou utilizando a API REST do Wordpress. Além disso, se os vídeos estiverem em um formato que não seja mp4, ou 3gp, terei algum problema? Se sim, como poderia contornar?